# Increment digit in every matched column except first match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this sample file below. This file is in a size of 50 MB. I want to match "AAA 2A" and except the first line of the match I want to increment the number in second column. Below input file has 3 lines that contain "AAA 2A" so except the very first line I want to increment the digit in each second column by 1.

Input file

```
[root@localhost]# cat sample.txt
AAA 2A
BBB 4A
AAA 2A
BBB 1A
AAA 2A
AAA 3A
BBB 2A
AAA 4A
```

Expected Output

```
[root@localhost]# cat output.txt
AAA 2A
BBB 4A
AAA 3A
BBB 1A
AAA 4A
AAA 3A
BBB 2A
AAA 4A
```

Comment: You have to show what you've tried so far, and why it doesn't work (Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service...).   Also, whoever downvoted should likely have left a comment to that effect as well.

Comment: @user3847894 : You tagged your question _awk_ and this is certainly a useful tool for the task, but in this case you should at least show the awk program you have written for this, and where you get stuck.

Comment: @user1934428 agree with you but closing for not showing code is a bit severe imo

Comment: It's not that alone. The OP used also _bash_ and _sed_ tags, and while I would recommend awk, the problem could also be solved with bash or sed, and I think the OP should in general be more clear in expressing, what he wants. Of course part of this would be showing the attempts he already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{counter=1}$0=="AAA 2A"{counter++;sub("2", counter)}1' <file>
```

counter starts at 1 and increases every time line is "AAA 2A". On those lines, it replace 2 with value of counter (so first time it gets it, value does not change because counter is at 2 already)